# How to prevent Hilt from picking dependency from a library?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger, dagger-hilt

Okay, let's make this simple.

I have created a simple library called `my-network-library` with two classes in it. First one is a Hilt module called `BaseNetworkModule`

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object BaseNetworkModule {

    // Client
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            // my default okhttp setup goes here 
            .build()
    }
}
```

and the second one is a simple class.

```kotlin
class MyAwesomeClass {
    fun doMagic() {
        // magic code goes here
    }
}
```

Now I want to use `MyAwesomeClass` in one of my App. So I added the dependency in the app.

```
implementation "com.theapache64:my-awesome-library-1.0.0"
```

I also have some network call implementation and I don't want to use `OkHttpClient` from `my-network-library`. So I've created a module in the app to get my own instance of `OkHttpClient`.

```kotlin
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object NetworkModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            // CUSTOM CONFIG GOES HERE 
            .build()
    }
}
```

Now am getting below error.

> error: [Dagger/DuplicateBindings] okhttp3.OkHttpClient is bound
> multiple times:

I know it's because of the `@Provides` declared in the `my-network-library`, but I didn't specify `includes` to the `@Module` annotation to inherit dependency from `BaseNetworkModule`. The issue may be fixed using `@Qualifier` annotation, but IMO, that'd be a workaround.

so my question is

- Why dependency from a library module comes into the app module without using `includes` of `@Module`?
- How to tell Hilt "Do not look for @Provides in external libraries (gradle dependencies) ?" unless I mark the module with `@Module(includes = XXXModule)`

Comment: [This](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/dependency-injection-in-a-multi-module-project-1a09511c14b7) might be helpful .

Comment: With dagger, it was working fine. To inherit dependency, we had to manually using `includes` option of `@Module` annotation. but with hilt, I don't know why it's by default includes all dependencies in the codebase.

Comment: You should use a qualifier marked as `internal` in the module so it doesn't leak outside

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Making the class `internal` would block accessing it entirely from the application. I want the class to be accessible via `includes` to maintain module inheritance.

Comment: You can use named annotation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why dependency from a library module comes into the app module without using includes of @Module?

Because Hilt was designed to be as simple as possible for a regular android dev.

Hilt is a simple dude: he sees `@Module @InstallIn` in the compiled code, he uses it. Think of `@InstallIn` as the `include` in the regular Dagger2. Just placed in a different spot.

---

> How to tell Hilt "Do not look for @Provides in external libraries (gradle dependencies) ?" unless I mark the module with @Module(includes = XXXModule)

Not possible. You'd have to not mark it with `@Module @InstallIn(...)`.

*In general I'm having troubles understanding why you would want that. How are you using Hilt features in `my-network-library`? Is it a shared module between different apps? And you want to include the module in some of those apps but not all of them?*

Comment: > `why you would want that?` - Think of `my-network-library` as a collection of simple boilerplate codes.  Thanks for responding @Bartek.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use qualifier ?

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.BINARY)
annotation class MyOkHttpClient

@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object BaseNetworkModule {

    // Client
    @MyOkHttpClient
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            // my default okhttp setup goes here 
            .build()
    }
}
```

You can separate OkHttpClients by this way and also continue taking advantages of hilt.